# Does MTLTriangleFillModeLines ignore degenerate triangles?

Tags: ios, graphics, metal

So I have a situation in my app where I want to draw the full screen as a mesh of triangles. I am doing this with what you would expect. A vertex buffer and an index buffer that goes along those vertices.

As I was debugging I wanted to see the edges of this mesh to help me visually figure out what was going on. This was when I discovered this image here. This was drawn using `[encoder setTriangleFillMode:MTLTriangleFillModeLines];` with a pipeline that has a fragment shader outputting green. You can see there are diagonals on every row here for whatever reason.

[image]

My question is essentially this. Does this look like a case where my mesh is simply wrong (probably the index buffer) or does MTLTriangleFillModeLines not really deal with degenerate triangles well?

Some additional important details:

- Drawing is done with `drawIndexedPrimitives` with `MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangleStrip`
- I am using `uint32_t` as the index type
- Indices are decided based on an old bit of example code from [here](https://github.com/robovm/apple-ios-samples/blob/master/GLCameraRipple/GLCameraRipple/RippleModel.m) since they also broke the screen up into a mesh.

Here is the copy of the code from Github

```
unsigned int index = 0;
for (int i=0; i<poolHeight-1; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<poolWidth; j++)
    {
        if (i%2 == 0)
        {
            // emit extra index to create degenerate triangle
            if (j == 0)
            {
                rippleIndicies[index] = i*poolWidth+j;
                index++;                    
            }

            rippleIndicies[index] = i*poolWidth+j;
            index++;
            rippleIndicies[index] = (i+1)*poolWidth+j;
            index++;

            // emit extra index to create degenerate triangle
            if (j == (poolWidth-1))
            {
                rippleIndicies[index] = (i+1)*poolWidth+j;
                index++;                    
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // emit extra index to create degenerate triangle
            if (j == 0)
            {
                rippleIndicies[index] = (i+1)*poolWidth+j;
                index++;
            }

            rippleIndicies[index] = (i+1)*poolWidth+j;
            index++;
            rippleIndicies[index] = i*poolWidth+j;
            index++;

            // emit extra index to create degenerate triangle
            if (j == (poolWidth-1))
            {
                rippleIndicies[index] = i*poolWidth+j;
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like expected behavior to me. Why not use [primitive restart](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Primitive_Restart) if you're concerned about degenerates being rendered when you've explicitly issued degenerates?

Comment: I thought degenerates would be completely ignored?

Answer (score 1):

Primitive restart would be a much better solution here. So as pointed out in the [Metal drawIndexedPrimitives](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlrendercommandencoder/1515520-drawindexedprimitives) placing a primitive restart index at the end of every row. So the new code should look roughly like:

```
uint32_t degenerate = 4294967295; //0xFFFFFFFF
assert(sizeof(uint32_t) == 4);
unsigned int index = 0;
for (int i=0; i<poolHeight-1; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<poolWidth; j++)
    {

        rippleIndicies[index++] = i*poolWidth+j;
        rippleIndicies[index++] = (i+1)*poolWidth+j;
    }
    rippleIndicies[index++] = degenerate;
}
```